# android activity restarted when orientation changes

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I read many posts about this problem like [this link][1] and one solution is add orientation configChanges to manifest and handle onConfigurationChanged event in order to prevent onCreate activity to be called again when rotation. I did it and event is triggered properly, however, after this execution, onCreate method is also executed! why? what I am missing? Thank you

manifest,

```
<activity 
            android:name="webPush"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

activity,

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      setContentView(R.layout.vistaaib);
    }

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vistaaib);
...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See http://web.archive.org/web/20120130201824/https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html —

> ```xml
> <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
>           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
>           android:label="@string/app_name">
> ```
>
> Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the will "screen size" also
> changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape
> orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to
> orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher you must use:
>
> ```
> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
> ```

Comment: still triggering onCreate after onConfigChanges event

Comment: Have you mentioned this in the AndroidManifest file under the activity that needs to be prevented from calling onCreate()

Comment: yes, as posted, webPush is the activity that its onCreate method needs to be prevented

Comment: found it! webPush class is inside a tabHost, so I must prevent rotation for tabHost class! changed and working. Thanks to make look inside!

Answer (score 2):

I Did this.
I added This code to manifest and it works perfect.

```
<activity
        android:name="?"
        android:label="@string/?"
        android:theme="@style/?" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

You will need to add this under you activity if you want to change something when the device is rotation.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this two lines of code in manifest file in that Activity.

Seem this will solve your problem.`<activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
             android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>`

Comment: still triggering onCreate after onConfigChanges event

Answer (score 1):

Your activity will be restarted on any configuration change. Most likely it is being restarted because the keyboard state changes. Try adding this to the activity's attributes:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: still triggering onCreate after onConfigChanges event

Comment: if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher, you must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation" value. That is, you must decalare android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Answer (score 0):

If you are working for API level 12 or lower

In menifest file, put following just after declaring your Activity Name.

```
    android:configChanges="orientation"
```

e.g.-

```
    <activity
        android:name=".NameOfYourActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"/>
```

And in android 3.2(API level 13) or higher version screen size also changes on rotation changes so declare this too.

for this,

```
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Could be the reason

Event :screenSize

The current available screen size has changed. This represents a change in the currently available size, relative to the current aspect ratio, so will change when the user switches between landscape and portrait. However, if your application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or higher device).
Added in API level 13.

so along with "orientation" add "screenSize" as well